# How to define callbacks from SQLITE to Android Activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write a callback from sqlite database to android activity. Currently i am inserting some data from the webservice in to db and then set it to listview.
I am running a service in the background which will continuously check for the new data. If there is new data it will update the database.
My prob is how to define the callback onupdate from sqlite to activity.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: read about `ContentProvider` / `ContentResolver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the result with observer pattern.
Your activity will implement an custom interface like RefreshableOnDBUpdateTrigger
in which you will re-load data from DB using standard DB querying mechanisms.

In your DB update class, you can call RefreshableOnDBUpdateTrigger.update() method which is essentially the method of your activity instance which fetches updated data from DB.

Refer observer pattern for implementation details.

Comment: The observer pattern is the obvious choice for this, but care must be taken to make sure that the activity is still active if the background service is setup to outlive the activity. In this case it would need to check if the activity is alive before attempting to call the callback.

Answer (score 0):

This would require user-defined functions, which are not supported by the Android database framework.

You have to call these callbacks explicitly in your database access code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to the interface callbacks would be to use an [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).  The DB code fetches data and then posts an event with the data.  Any registered classes would receive the event.